# Should I Enable Drive Alive mode when i trying to download big files?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I am using Amphetamine for prevent mac from sleeping when i try to update my apps and downloading big files but in its Quick Setting there is an option named "Enable Drive Alive" which I don't know to enable it or not, what it really does? Should i enable it or not?

Comment: Vote to close as off topic. More about `Amphetamine` rather an Apple product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Enable Drive Alive" mode prevent drives from sleeping. Drives sleep when they are not used for a while for a variety of different reasons, including allowing the drive to last longer.

From the [Aphetamine App Store Page](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12)

> - Keep your Mac (and optionally its display and drives) awake
> - Keep drives (HDDs/SSDs) connected to your Mac awake

There is a similar option in System Preferences>Energy Saver>Put Hard Disks to Sleep when possible. This feature does the opposite, it puts Hard drives to sleep after a certain amount of inactivity.

From [Apples notes on this feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202824):

> ### Put hard disks to sleep when possible
>
> This setting powers down the hard drive motor when you aren't reading or writing files from the drive. Solid-state drives (SSDs)
>   don’t have moving parts, so this setting doesn’t affect Mac computers
>   that use only SSDs to store data.
>
> Consider deselecting this option if you have an internal or external
>   non-SSD drive and you use apps—for example, pro audio or video editing
>   software—that work better with continued read and write access to the
>   hard disk.

So to answer your question. **No, the drive will be active if it is being used (to download files), therefore there is no reason to use this feature.**

Other information: https://www.howtogeek.com/227561/how-to-prevent-your-mac-from-sleeping-without-changing-any-settings/